# How solve kafka.errors.UnrecognizedBrokerVersion: UnrecognizedBrokerVersion?

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Create docker containers from

https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker.git

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test-topic:5:2"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

start docker containers

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                NAMES
1479a7dc96fa        wurstmeister/kafka       "start-kafka.sh"         42 minutes ago      Up 42 minutes       0.0.0.0:32785->9092/tcp                              kafka-docker_kafka_2
08e5017dae2b        wurstmeister/kafka       "start-kafka.sh"         42 minutes ago      Up 42 minutes       0.0.0.0:32786->9092/tcp                              kafka-docker_kafka_3
d4f3d17e81b2        wurstmeister/kafka       "start-kafka.sh"         44 minutes ago      Up 44 minutes       0.0.0.0:32784->9092/tcp                              kafka-docker_kafka_1
72b0fbe553b5        wurstmeister/zookeeper   "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   44 minutes ago      Up 44 minutes       22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp   kafka-docker_zookeeper_1
```

checked topics

```
$ docker exec -it kafka-docker_kafka_3 bash
bash-4.4# /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 172.19.0.3:2181 --list
test-topic
bash-4.4# exit
exit
```

pip3.7 install kafka-python=1.4.7

maked client by python

```
import os
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
producer = KafkaConsumer(security_protocol="PLAINTEXT", bootstrap_servers=os.environ.get('KAFKA_HOST', 'localhost:2181'))
```

try to start returned error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/drno/IdeaProjects/prometheus_dirs_and_files_node_exporter/zookeeper_kafka.py", line 9, in <module>
    producer = KafkaConsumer(security_protocol="PLAINTEXT", bootstrap_servers=os.environ.get('KAFKA_HOST', 'localhost:2181'))
  File "/opt/python/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 354, in __init__
    self._client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, **self.config)
  File "/opt/python/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
  File "/opt/python/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 908, in check_version
    version = conn.check_version(timeout=remaining, strict=strict, topics=list(self.config['bootstrap_topics_filter']))
  File "/opt/python/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/conn.py", line 1228, in check_version
    raise Errors.UnrecognizedBrokerVersion()
kafka.errors.UnrecognizedBrokerVersion: UnrecognizedBrokerVersion
```

How solve this problem?

Comment: localhost:2181 is Zookeeper, not a bootstrap server

Comment: change to localhost:32784,localhost:32785,localhost:32786 - connect - OK

Comment: how number of port to connect bootstrap-server?

Comment: You only show one broker in your compose file. It says "9092". Where are you getting 3 brokers with different ports?

Comment: create container- docker-compose up -d , after scale docker-compose scale kafka=3

Comment: That still doesn't answer how `9092` became `3278x`

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace says you are connecting to `localhost:2181` (Zookeeper), not Kafka.

I suggest you make your Python code into a container. Add the correct service connection string via an enviromenet variable

```
app:
  build: app  # where app is a folder containing your Python code + Dockerfile
  environment:
    KAFKA_HOST: kafka:9092
```

And please remove `/var/run/docker.sock` from the mounts

Otherwise, you need to connect to `localhost:32784,localhost:32785,localhost:32786` from your host machine

Comment: please write full wrking docker-compose.yml)

Comment: What I provided is the full thing that you can copy and paste into your existing one. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build